# Insert a value in a cell with no decimal VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am coding a macro, and I need to take a value from a sheet, and save this value in a variable. Then open an another sheet, and put this value into a cell, but if that cell contains an another value, I have to increase. Like, the cell "B2" has "52", and I have to put more "5", it would have to be "57".

```
Sheets("BP").Select
VarQty = Cells(i, QtyCol).Value  //this is que value

Sheets("Manuf").Select
Cells(i,j).value = Cells(i,j).value + VarQty
```

When I try it, it returns a decimal number, but it can't happens.

Comment: Unless it's a simple formatting issue, declare your variables as `Int` or `Long` that accept only whole numbers.

Comment: I just tried this. But it returns the same value, with decimal numbers. :(

Comment: Your `VarQty` probably contains a number with a decimal part that is hidden because the column is formatted for `Decimal Places: = 0`  and the cells  in `Sheet("Manuf")` are formatted as `General`. When a number is formatted to hide the decimal it still contains the decimal part and when added to a whole number in a cell that is formatted as `General` it will show the decimal numbers.